# Get serial number from the extracted hwid.csv and use it to rename the csv file

Tags: azure, powershell, autopilot

Hello Brilliant People,

Good day.

I may have a simple query here.
The code below generates the hardware ID for Windows Autopilot and I am trying to rename it with the serial number of the machine.

Please let me know if this is possible.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Set-Location D:\\HWID
.\Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1 -OutputFile D:\HWID\AutoPilotHWID.csv
```

Just need to use the device serial number and output it as the filename :)

```
Device Serial Number,Windows Product ID,Hardware Hash
BXA6379CYA,,T0HuAgEAHAAAAAoAfwRhSgAACgAIBWFKA9ryKSACCQUCABAACQABAAIABAABAAAABQAZABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAACAAEAAwMAEQBHZW51aW5lSW50ZWwABAA0AEludGVsKFIpIENvcmUoVE0pIGk1LTQzMDBVIENQVSBAIDEuO
```

Appreciate the response.

Comment: Where did you obtain `Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1`?

Comment: Hello @MathiasR.Jessen 

Thanks for you quick response.
I've initially generated it using Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo 

Placed it in the same directory for the script above.

Comment: so ... where is the SN? [*grin*] if it is in the CSV, then load the file with `Import-CSV` and get it from there. if you want help with that, add the CSV data to your Question.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey apologies I have edited my post with the downloadable csv for everyone's reference :)

Comment: @BrainBug - thank you for the added info & sample data. i see that SantiagoSquarzon has posted an Answer. it uses the same method that i would recommend for getting the SN from that CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.2) to rename a file and [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.2) to get the Serial from your CSV:

```sh
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Set-Location D:\\HWID
.\Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1 -OutputFile D:\HWID\AutoPilotHWID.csv
$serial = (Import-Csv D:\HWID\AutoPilotHWID.csv).'Device Serial Number' | Select-Object -First 1
Rename-Item -LiteralPath D:\HWID\AutoPilotHWID.csv -NewName ($serial + '.csv')
```